# Trying to implement the login functionality but the model is not correctly identified in laravel

Tags: php, multi-tenant, laravel-10

I have written a login controller function as follows:

```
use App\Models\Tenant\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\UserPurchasedSubscription;
use App\Models\User as RootUser;

public function login(Request $request)
    {
        if (!$request->isMethod('post')) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Unauthenticated'
            ], 401);
        }
        try {
            $request->validate([
                'email' => 'required|string|email',
                'password' => 'required|string',
            ]);
        } catch (\Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException $e) {
            return $this->returnErrorResponse(self::COMPONENT_CODE, 105, array_column($e->errors(), 0), 422);
        }

        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        $credentials['valid_until'] = null;

        $user = User::where('email', $credentials['email'])->first();
        
        if (!$user) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'error',
                'message' => 'Incorrect Login, Please check user credentials.',
                'statusCode'    => 401
            ], 200);
        }

        $status = $this->isUserActive($user);
        
        if ($status == false) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'error',
                'message' => 'You cannot log in since your account has been disabled.',
                'statusCode'    => 401
            ], 200);
        }

        $root_user = RootUser::where('email', $credentials['email'])->first();
        dd($root_user);
        if ($root_user !== null && $root_user->is_inactive == 1) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'error',
                'message' => 'You cannot log in since your account has been disabled.',
                'statusCode'    => 401
            ], 200);
        }
        if ($root_user->login_count < 3) {
            $root_user->login_count = ($root_user->login_count + 1);
            $root_user->save();
        }

        if ($root_user !== null) {
            if ($root_user->is_stripe_subscription_done == 1) {
                $status = $this->isSubscriptionActive($root_user);
            } else {
                $status = true;
            }
        }

        if ($status == false) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'error',
                'message' => 'You have no active Subscription linked with your account, kindly login to Admin portal and purchase a new plan to proceed.',
                'statusCode' => 401
            ], 200);
        }

        if (!is_null($user->valid_until)) {
            if (!$this->isValidUser($user)) {
                return response()->json([
                    'status' => 'error',
                    'message' => 'Your Trial account has expired. Please Login to RoleScale Admin Portal.',
                    'statusCode' => 401
                ], 200);
            } else {
                $status = true;
            }
        }

        if ($status == false) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'error',
                'message' => 'You have no active Subscription linked with your account, kindly login to Admin portal and purchase a new plan to proceed.',
                'statusCode' => 401
            ], 200);
        }

        $credentials['valid_until'] = $user->valid_until;
        $token = Auth::attempt($credentials);
        if (!$token) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'error',
                'message' => 'Incorrect Login, Please check user credentials.',
                'statusCode'    => 401
            ], 422);
        }

        $user = Auth::user();
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'success',
            'tenant_id' => $user['domain_id'],
            'authorisation' => [
                'token' => $token,
                'type' => 'bearer',
            ]
        ]);
    }
```

the other functions used in the code is as follows:

```
protected function isValidUser(User $user)
    {
        $validUntil = $user->valid_until;

        // If valid_until is null or it is in the future, the user is valid
        return is_null($validUntil) || Carbon::now()->lessThanOrEqualTo($validUntil);
    }


    public function isSubscriptionActive(RootUser $user)
    {
        $subscription_details = UserPurchasedSubscription::where('user_id', $user->id)->first();
        if ($subscription_details !== null) {
            if ($subscription_details->is_active === 0 && $subscription_details->subscription_status === 'canceled') {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }


    public function isUserActive(User $user)
    {
        $user_details = User::where('id', $user->id)->first();
        if ($user_details !== null) {
            if ($user_details->is_active == false) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

the problem arises when I am trying to log in a user present in the users table representing the use App\Models\Tenant\User model, it is always trying to fetch the record from the users table of the use App\Models\User as RootUser model, so the log in is not possible.

Kindly help.
If you could suggest where am I going wrong.